Kdenlive, fade out cannot applied on certain clips. why and when?
Lastest Kdenlive 24.02.2 Mac os
I am about to fade in a custom sfx, and fade out original audio; at the same time. Somehow kdenlive yield cannot add effect to the selected clip I really wonder why. and how to overcome this?
I try not to place the fade in and fade out on the same time, but it yield the same.
Presumably, it is possible, someone might explain when this happen?
